# Unclear behaviour of Position, lists and functions in general

Tags: functions

apologies for the title, but I have such a confusion about my question that I haven't been able to formalise a clear title.

My question arise from the "discrepancy" between the results of the following code:

```
Position[{0, 1/2}, x_ /; x != 0]
Position[{0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, x_ /; x != 0]
```

> {{2}}
>
> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2}}

While I can recover the result by slightly modifying the code:

```
Position[{0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, x_ /; x != 0,1]
```

> {{2}}

it's still not completely clear what's happening, and if it's supposed to be like that.

Let's see the difference between the two cases:

```
FullForm@{0, 1/2}
FullForm@{0, 1/Sqrt[2]}
```

> List[0,Rational[1,2]]
>
> List[0,Power[2,Rational[-1,2]]]

At a first sight, there isn't anything weird happening, but they behave differently.
By looking at the second element of the list, I get this:

```
(1/2)[[1]]
(1/Sqrt[2])[[1]]
(1/Sqrt[2])[[2]]
```

> "Part specification (1/2)[[1]] is longer than depth of object."
>
> 2
>
> -1/2

In principle, if I have a function I can access it's arguments by indexing:

```
fun[ind1, ind2][[1]]
fun[ind1, ind2][[2]]
```

> ind1
>
> ind2

Why I can't access the elements of the first function (Rational[1,2]) but I can access the elements of the second one (Power[2,Rational[-1,2]])?

I've been trying to look at the attributes of the two functions:

```
Attributes[Rational]
Attributes[Power]
```

> {Protected}
>
> {Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Protected}

But I'm not sure that the answer lies in here...

To sum up my questions:

1. Is Position supposed to work as I showed in the first piece of code?
2. Why I can index the arguments of Power, but not of Rational?

Comment: `AtomQ@Rational[1, 2]`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! I was surprised I couldn't find any post that discussed this already, but I must have used wrong keywords :) btw, it's still confusing to me why Rational are atomic elements even if they are composed by two integers (and the function takes two arguments)...